# Detecting duplicate or similar PDFs using elasticsearch

Tags: pdf, elasticsearch, duplicates, similarity

I'm trying to find a good way to identify whether I have duplicate/highly similar PDFs in a system if they're not exactly alike (ie checksums are different because the pages in the pdf have been either been rearranged, deleted, or merged with other pages).

So a simple example would be:

Original PDF contains pages (A, B, C, D)

New PDF entering system contains pages (D, B, C, A, E, F) or (D, G, H, I, B) or any other iteration where some of the content is resides somewhere else in the original PDF.

Any suggestions for robust methods to determine match/similarity thresholds? Such as identifying that a new PDF is 80% similar to the original.

We are using elasticsearch for search purposes in our system but I haven't found a good way to query or use the score to come up with a useful percentage/number to use as a success threshold.

Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that given a set of drawings in a PDF page there are literally infinite possible PDFs that can generate the same drawings?

Comment: How exactly do you want to do this? It's one thing to calculate the similarity between 1 document and another, but how do you know which two to compare? Are you going to try to compare the new document to all existing documents in the index?

Comment: @JohnPetrone I think I was going to compare the new document to the entire existing index because the goal is to try to raise any documents that contain the same content. I was considering ways to do this efficiently and so far came up with grabbing random blocks of text to run queries with. Do you think you may have a better solution? Thanks!